# exporting EAR from websphere and importing it to Jboss

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, websphere-8

i am migrating my J2EE application from websphere 8 to Jboss EAP 6.1. Would it be ok if i just export the .EAR file from Rational Application Developer to Eclipse (Kepler) running Jboss EAP 6.1? or should i be making some changes to the EAR before deploying?

Comment: Only thing to do is try. If you hit some problems ask about them.

Comment: @ctomc : ya that's what i did and i figured it out myself.. thx for the response.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. Since the .EAR contains IBM Websphere specific data in it and the JBoss server use a different set of XML files, it won't be compatible with it. But the .WAR file can be extracted from the .EAR and can be used in JBoss provided any IBM dependent references are removed from the project.